# Pass prop to parent in Vuetify and Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I pass the dark mode value from navbar (child) to app.vue (parent)?

Within my navbar component I have a switch to enable/disable dark mode. I'd like to pass that dark data up to the parent (app.vue) to change the entire app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Vue's custom events interface. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

In your child navbar component you can have a method:

```
handleThemeChange: function (mode) {
    this.$emit('handle-theme-change', { mode });
}
```

And then in your parent App component watch for that event:

```
<App v-on:handle-theme-change="handleThemeChange" />
```

Then your app component can have a method `handleThemeChange` that actually handles the change. The `handleThemeChange` method in your app component will accept the object as a parameter.